# Read in mp4 video file with audio, edit the frames and write them to a new file with the audio

Tags: matlab, video-processing

I am reading a filename.mp4 video file in MATLAB. I want to edit the images, however, I want to keep the audio intact. Using `VideoReader` and `VideoWriter` only does the images part. I used `vision.VideoFileReader` and 'vision.VideoFileWriter'. I read the video and audio files, then take the image  and add a picture next to it. Then write the frame and the audio associated with it. The final video shows the picture I added, but not the original image. Any help appreciated.

```matlab
v = VideoReader('movie.mp4');
nfr = v.NumberofFrames;
clear v;
vR = vision.VideoFileReader('movie.mp4','AudioOutputPort',1);
fr = vR.info.VideoFrameRate;
vW = vision.VideoFileWriter('filename.avi','AudioInputPort',1,'FrameRate',fr);

pic = imread('picture.png');%read picture
[a1,b1,~] = size(pic);% get picture size to be resized.


for i = 1:nfr
    [I,audio] = vR();
    I = permute(I,[2,1,3]);%rotate 90 degrees
    if i == 1%resize the picture
        [a,b,~] = size(I);
        pic = imresize(pic,[a,a/a1*b1]);
    end
    I = [I pic];%combine picture and movie frame
    vW(I,audio);%write frame and audio
end
release(vR);
release(vW);
```

Comment: It should be `true`; not `'true'` which is what the error message is also telling you

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But I am not sure where to go from here

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```matlab
v = VideoReader('movie.mp4');
nfr = v.NumberofFrames;
clear v;
vR = vision.VideoFileReader('movie.mp4','AudioOutputPort',1,'VideoOutDataType','uint8');
%default of VideoOutDataType is 'single', converting it to a similar format is essential
fr = vR.info.VideoFrameRate;
vW = vision.VideoFileWriter('filename.avi','AudioInputPort',1,'FrameRate',fr);

pic = imread('picture.png');%read picture
[a1,b1,~] = size(pic);% get picture size to be resized.


for i = 1:nfr
    [I,audio] = vR();
    I = permute(I,[2,1,3]);%rotate 90 degrees
    if i == 1%resize the picture
        [a,b,~] = size(I);
        pic = imresize(pic,[a,a/a1*b1]);%resizing the pic to same height as movie frame %with proportional width
    end
    I = [I pic];%combine picture and movie frame
    vW(I,audio);%write frame and audio
end
release(vR);
release(vW);
```